# Does sizeof(var) always work in C?

Tags: c, variables, sizeof, binaryfiles

Whenever I want to read or write into a *binary file* using C, I do use the `fread()` and `fwrite()` functions. They need as a parameter the bytes of the datum that is being read or written so I use the `sizeof()` function. Now the question is:

The books says that I should declare a function like this:

```
fread(&variable,sizeof(TYPE_OF_VAR),quantity,file);
```

I've use the following statement which works most of the time but not always:

```
fread(&variable,sizeof(VARIABLE),quantity,file);
```

Why does it works sometimes but sometimes it doesn't?
Does it depends on the *type* of the variable *(int, char, etc)*?
Does it depends on the *quantity* of the datum that I use?

Comment: Could you please post an example of when this doesn't work, including the source code?

Comment: It works when the identifier (the variable) is for an object; it doesn't work when the identifier is for a pointer to object.

Comment: `sizeof` applied to a type, in parentheses, gives the size of the type. Applied to an expression, without parentheses, it gives the size of the type of the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to keep in mind is that `sizeof` is based on what the compiler knows about the type at compile time (ignoring VLA's for now). If you give it a variable, it will use the type of that variable.

So, the only time I can think of where it wouldn't work as you expect is with **pointers**.

basically what it boils down to is this:

```
int x[5];
int *y = &x[0];
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
sizeof(x); // == sizeof(int) * 5
sizeof(y); // == sizeof(int *)
sizeof(p); // == sizeof(int *)
```

This gets tricky when dealing with functions because arrays **decay** to pointers when passed to a function. Also note that all 3 of these are exactly equivalent:

```
int func(int *p);
int func(int p[5]);
int func(int p[]);
```

in all 3, p is a **pointer**, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

See this Stack Overflow question for a discussion of heap vs. stack: *[What and where are the stack and heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)*.

`sizeof()` on heap elements, like pointers, will return the size of the pointer, not the number of elements that the pointer can store.

However, `sizeof()` on stack elements: arrays or `const char *` will return the length of the array or string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *a = NULL;
    char b[10] = "abcdefghi";

    printf("sizeof(b): %zu\n", sizeof(b));

    a = malloc(LENGTH + 1);
    if (a) {
        *(a + LENGTH) = '\0';
        memset(a, ' ', LENGTH);
        fprintf(stdout, "a (before memcpy):\t[%s]\n", a);
        printf("sizeof(a), before: %zu\n", sizeof(a));
        memcpy(a, b, sizeof(b) - 1);
        fprintf(stdout, "a (after memcpy):\t[%s]\n", a);
        printf("sizeof(a), after: %zu\n", sizeof(a));
        free(a);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To compile:

```
$ gcc -Wall sizeofTest.c -o sizeofTest
```

Output:

```
$ ./sizeofTest
sizeof(b): 10
a (before memcpy):     [                                                                                                    ]
sizeof(a), before: 8
a (after memcpy):      [abcdefghi                                                                                           ]
sizeof(a), after: 8
```

On my platform, a `char *` points to a memory address that takes up eight bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It will always work.

```
int main()
{
    char a[10];
    int b[10];
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",sizeof(char),sizeof(int), sizeof(a),sizeof(b), sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(b[0]) );
}
```

Try the above code. You should see (depending on compiler, mine has char as 1byte and integer as 4 bytes) 1,4,10,40,1,4

It is not different for fread or fwrite or wherever you use it.